# How do I call a method in a adapter who is initialized in a fragment that is contained in an Activity?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, interface

Im trying to use a button in my recycleviewers on click to run a method that is in my Main Activity. This recyleview is intialized in a fragment that is nested in that Activity.

So it goes:

MainActivity - > Fragment -> RecycleViewAdapter

How can RecycleviewAdapter call a method from MainActivity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1:
Create an interface in the `Activity`. Pass it to the `Fragment`, then to the `Adapter`.

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if(context instanceof YouInterface){
        listener = (YourInterface)context;
    } 
}
```

Then pass the listener in the `Adapter`s constructor

Option 2: BroadcastReceiver / EventBus

Comment: When in the activity/fragment/adapter lifecycle should I pass it? could you give me an example